# Can I ask a question to answer it, instead of pushing a personal philosophy?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask a question to answer it, instead of pushing a personal philosophy?

i.e. to see if my answer is a good one, by looking at votes and comments.

Comment: the problem being that then the answer would likely have no references, if it really is a personal philosophy. hmm, i gotta think about this

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can answer your own question, as long as the question is on topic. If you just want to try out a new theory, it seems your answer would be primarily opinion based. You can then better ask a question about the implications of such a theory.

If you give an example of what kind of question you're thinking of, this can be made more specific.